# is it possible to bypass cookie protection to perform a CSRF on HUAWEI HG531 v1 router?

Tags: web-browser, xss, cookies, csrf, router

the AJAX login script

```
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr1.open("post", 'https://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi', false);
xhr1.send("Username=admin&Password=6836394be82df057e085fc344c6179d1b50b30224ad0SJ0GQrNWmpsXCSk5so7o73f93282&challange=SJ0GQrNWmpsXCSk5so7o");
```

the problem is it gives me this error

> Login Failure: Browser did not support Cookie. Please enable Cookie

and i can't send a cookie header cause it's a Forbidden header name ..... the page after i press login it sets the required cookies to perform a login . is there any way around this ?

some lines from the page source code that i think are important

```
var strCookie = document.cookie;

document.cookie = cookie;

var cookie = "Language=en" + expires + ";

var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible if only you could run the script on the same router page or with same url with some kind of local [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) to [trick the browser that](https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/rebinder.html) you are sending the request to the same site that the request is made from and both are the router page(address-ip) and redirecting only after you set the cookies manually ... or if some how you could sniff/get the after successful login cookies you would skip all this headache...check the both links for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

By default, XMLHttpRequest does not include cookies. Use [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) to send cookies along.

As an alternative, you can create a [HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and submit that with JavaScript. This sends cookies along by default.

Comment: xhr.withCredentials didn't help ...  "you can create a HTML form and submit that with JavaScript" you mean i copy the page form into a page and input the required data  then trigger  the submit function ?  [the page source code](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d372b2479402)  here is the login button code `<a id="btnLogin" href="javascript:SubmitFormWithChallange(0);">` ...

Comment: "This sends cookies along by default"  i don't think so cause it sets the cookies into the browser sends it by it self in login cause it's the same domain ! and if it sets it in our page it won't help in any thing . " different domain "